# nhibernate composite-id with not existing key-many-to-one record

Tags: nhibernate, composite-id

i have old legacy DB which has dead links in their tables. I have class mapped in nhibernate like this:

```
<class name="Visible" table="table_visible">
    <composite-id>
        <key-many-to-one column="object_id" name="ObjectA" />
        <key-many-to-one column="sub_object_id" name="SubObject" />
    </composite-id>
    <property column="visible" name="VisibleRow" />
</class>
```

and:

```
public class Visible
{
    public virtual ObjectAClass ObjectA { get; set; }
    public virtual SubObjectClass SubObject { get; set; }
    public virtual bool VisibleRow { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = ((Visible)obj);
        return this.ObjectA.Equals(other.ObjectA) && this.SubObject.Equals(other.SubObject);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.ObjectA.GetHashCode() + (this.SubObject != null? this.SubObject.GetHashCode(): 0);
    }
}
```

Now all works fine when all joins in database are correct, but when i find such sub_object_id which doesnt have entity, nhibernate throws me error

```
No row with the given identifier exists:[SubObject#123]
```

Is there a way to map composite key so that when its subentity is not found, the whole entity wouldnt be loaded (like with inner join)?

NHibernate v2.0.50727

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Daniel Schilling idea of fetch Visible entities with a where exists sub-query, found  that there is `loader` element available in mappings.

```
<class name="ObjectA" table="table_object">
    .........   
    <set name="VisibleList" cascade="all" lazy="false" inverse="true">
        <key column="object_id" />
        <one-to-many class="Visible" />
        <loader query-ref="valid_entities"/>
    </set>

</class>
<sql-query name="valid_entities">
    <load-collection alias="v" role="ObjectA.VisibleList"/>
    SELECT {v.*}
    FROM table_visible v
    INNER JOIN table_sub_entities e ON e.sub_entity_id=v.sub_entity_id
    WHERE v.object_id=?
</sql-query>
```

And nothing else needed to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<key-many-to-one column="sub_object_id" name="SubObject" not-found="ignore" />
```

... may be helpful.  From the [NHibernate Documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone)...

> `ignore` will treat a missing row as a null association

Please be aware of the performance penalty associated with using this option.  Whenever NHibernate fetches a `Visible` entity, it will also have to fetch `SubObject`.  If you don't go ahead and fetch it in your query, this means that NHibernate will be issuing lots of lazy loads.

This doesn't meet your "when its sub-entity is not found, the whole entity wouldn't be loaded" goal.  Instead NHibernate would give you an entity with a null sub-entity.  If you want that inner-join-like behavior, then I think you would need to fetch your `Visible` entities with a `where exists` sub-query to make sure the `SubObject` actually exists.

The **best** option would be to fix the data in the database and add a foreign key constraint.

I just ran across this: [Relations with not-found="ignore"](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/relations-not-foundignore).  I promise I'm not copying Ricci's content - I'm writing this from my own experience.

Comment: i have tried using not-found=ignore,but result was same. maybe i missed some other places to check if subentity is not null and thats why error was remaining, but i think then error would change to "null reference". my guess it doesnt work on keys.  p.s. i should have mentioned i tried it, gethascode method still has some garbage left from that try

Comment: where exists check may be good solution tho, i am going to google it, because atm i write nasty hacks with mapping sub_entity_id and SubEntity object separately, hiding them under property and then adding null checks everywhere.